# Removing an element Array of Struct Issues in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a problem in removing an element of array of structs in C. So, I have a program that have 2 options, Add and Delete. The problem is, when I delete an element from the array of struct, and add another element, the output will show the element that i deleted before, and the new element I added is not showing. How can I fix this problem?

This is my program I tried to make

```
#include "stdio.h"

struct itemlist
{
    char name[25];
    int quantity;
};

int main()
{
    int progress,processNum,i,sizeStruct = 0;
    struct itemlist items[105];
    printf("How many progress you want to do?\n");
    scanf("%d",&progress); getchar();

    for(i = 0; i < progress ; i++){
        scanf("%d",&processNum); getchar();        
        switch (processNum){
        case 1: // Add
            printf("Name of item :\n");
            scanf("%[^\n]",items[i].name); getchar();
            printf("How many items?:\n");
            scanf("%d",&items[i].quantity); getchar();
            sizeStruct++;
            printf("Success to add!!\n"); 
            break;
        case 2: // Delete from database, and its last index can be replaced.
            int index3;
            printf("Which index do you wanna delete?\n");
            scanf("%d",&index3); getchar();
            for(int k = index3-1; k < sizeStruct - 1; k++){
                items[k] = items[k + 1];
            }
            sizeStruct--;
            printf("Your item has been deleted.\n"); 
            break;
        }
    }
    // Print All last Items
    printf("Items: \n");
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeStruct; j++){
        printf("%s\n",items[j].name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the input & output :

```
How many progress you want to do?
4
1
Name of item :
Cola-Cola
How many items?:
3
Success to add!!
1
Name of item :
Sprite
How many items?:
4
Success to add!!
2
Which index do you wanna delete?
2
Your item has been deleted.
1
Name of item :
Beer
How many items?:
8
Success to add!!
Items:
Cola-Cola // supposed to be Beer
Sprite
```

But my program is working while I didnt add any items after deletion. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You always add an item at position i but when you delete an item you shift your array one position to the left, overwriting the item you want to delete, but you are not updating i. 
When you want to delete item 2, the for-loop

> for(int k = index3-1; k < sizeStruct - 1; k++)

will not do anything because k=1, sizeStruct=2. This is fine since there is no item after "Sprite" to overwrite it. But i will be incremented after this. Thus your array looks like this at the end

```
i   : 0         1      2           3
item: Cola-Cola Sprite /*Garbage*/ Beer
```

and you are only printing the first 2 items at the end.

You might want do add i-=2 inside "case 2" so i is the position where new items should be added. 
Also note that in your example input/output when you delete item 2 you overwrite "Sprite" and add "Beer", so the expected output would be

```
Items:
Cola-Cola
Beer
```